# How can I translate ActiveRecord model class name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

What is the simplest way to get translated name of ActiveRecord model class when I have an instance of it?

For example - I have model class like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

I have an instance of the class:

```
category = Category.first
```

And I have YAML file `config/locales/cs.yml`:

```
cs:
  activerecord:
    models:
      category: Kategorie
```

And I need to do this dynamicaly, even when I don't previously know with what model class' instance I will be dealing. So I don't want to explicitly specify "activerecord.models.category".

Is there an easy way to do this? I know, that I can do something like this

```
"activerecord.models.#{category.class.name.underscore}"
```

But there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

See:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

So, for example, on an AR class use:

```
Person.model_name.human
```

or from an AR instance:

```
person.class.model_name.human
```

Comment: Instead of `human`, which adds spaces and downcases all but the first letter, I found `name` to be more useful. So: `SomePerson.model_name.name` which returns `SomePerson`

Answer (score -1):

Check out [constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) and [classify](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify).

Comment: Thanks you for answer. But these methods do not solve this problem. As I mentioned, I can use [underscore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-underscore) and construct the actual "path" to translation. But I ask, if there is some method that can directly translate model instance (or the model class itself).